# How to add transition to height, to block with height:auto?

Tags: css, height, css-transitions

I have a block with style `height:auto`. Fading happens by adding class to this element. It doesn't work with `height:auto` but if I will enter random height to this block: `height: 250px;` fading will work.

So, how to make it works with `height:auto`? If I explained badly - say it, I can to re explain my problem.

Comment: post the script segments on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when CSS change the height (or width) form auto to a value it snaps to 0 first cutting all transitions (same issue when trying to apply opacity transition with a change in display).

A workaround would be, on load, to set the height of the objects to their own offsetHeight.
Basically like using a random number (that you noticed works) but which is not random.